# Inherit CSS fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

After dragging elements using fullCalendar.io, I need to respect the original element CSS, in the example the text is respected and I do not get the class to be respected.

```
$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {
  $(this).data('event', {
    title: $.trim($(this).text()),
    className: ¿?, //Dont Work!
    stick: true
  });

  $(this).draggable({
    zIndex: 999,
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 0
  });

});
```

But:

```
className: 'lc', //Work!
```

html class

```
.fc-event-container .lc{
    background: #E74C3C;
  }
```

[Look](https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/demos/external-dragging.html)

Comment: `className: ¿?` ...is this really a className you used in your CSS?

Comment: @ADyson not, is a 'lc', 'mt', 'sh'...

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, sorry. My point was I don't think you can use those symbols as a class name or variable name.

Comment: @ADyson  I know I can not use symbols as variables. I need to extract the class from the object, something like

className: $ (this) .css ('background')

with "¿?" I refer to ... 'any ideas?'

Comment: So I don't get your point then, what's wrong with using `className: 'lc'`?